# Ajaxinate Endless scolling has stopped product Quick View from working

Tags: ajax, shopify, infinite-scroll

I am using Shopify "Streamline Theme" with quick product view and  I recently added infinite scroll to products on each collection using Ajaxinate.js.

When I open a collection page it loads with some products which is supposed to do, The products already there work fine with quick view and quick add to cart and also.

The Infinite scroll works fine and it loads new product fine but the problem is raised when the new products loaded through AJAX call doesn't have work with the quick view function.

I have tried to create a callback function to activate the quick view with no success, using the theme initialisation code with no success.

```
function callBack(){
 theme.init();
 theme.initQuickShop();
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
var endlessClick = new Ajaxinate({
  method: "scroll",
  loadingText: 'Loading...',
  callback: callBack
});
});
```

Edit -------

My problem, is that when the page is loaded only the initial loaded products quickview elements are loaded in the DOM. When the scroll more button is clicked, the newly loaded products are loaded without their respective quickview elements. Hence why the quickview does't work for them. The theme.js file comes with this initialisation code:

```
theme.reinitProductGridItem = function($scope) {
if (AOS) {
  AOS.refreshHard();
}

if (theme.settings.currenciesEnabled) {
  theme.currencySwitcher.ajaxrefresh();
}

// Reload quick shop buttons
theme.initQuickShop(true);

// Refresh reviews app
if (window.SPR) {
  SPR.initDomEls();SPR.loadBadges();
}

// Re-register product templates in quick view modals.
// Will not double-register.
sections.register('product-template', theme.Product, $scope);

// Re-hook up collapsible box triggers
theme.collapsibles.init();
```

};

I have tried to integrate this into a callback  but no success, the quickview modal doesn't seem to load for the newly loaded products:

```
function callBack(){
   ReloadSmartWishlist();
   var $container = $('#CollectionSection');
   theme.reinitProductGridItem($container);
  // I have tried the following init qith no success:
 // theme.init();
 // theme.initQuickShop(true);
 // theme.initQuickShop();
 //  sections.register('product-template', theme.Product, $container);
// AOS.refreshHard();

};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var endlessClick = new Ajaxinate({
    method: "click",
    loadingText: 'Loading...',
    offset: 0,
    callback: callBack
  });
});
```

I am missing something but what? :/
Note for other things like loading products images with the callback and the wishlist app, it  works as intended...

Answer (score 0):

When you load elements via AJAX and if the events are not attached to a parent element that is not removed from the DOM, those elements will not have an attached event to them.

The term used here is event delegation.

Here is an example of **non-delegated** event:

```
document.querySelectorAll('a').addEventListener('click', function(){
 // Do something
})
```

Since you are attaching the event to the existing "a" elements if you add new 'a' via AJAX those elements will not have the event since Javascript already attached all the events and it will not reattach them if you don't specifically recall them again.

---

Here is an example of a **delegated** event:

```
document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('click', function(target){
    let target = event.target;
    if (target.tagName === 'A'){
        // Do something here
    }
})
```

Where we attach the event to the body tag ( where it's a better idea to attach it to a closer none-modified parent element of the ajax items ) and once we click we check if our target tag is an "a" and do something then.

---

So long story short, you will need to delegate the quick cart link so that it works after you load the items via AJAX.

Comment: Thanks @drip for the clarification. I am trying to wrap my head around it, considering the specificty of what I'm trying to achieve. I have edited my topic to explain my problem better.

Answer (score 0):

Drip is correct you need to delegate your event, but for people like me it's hard to completely understand how to do that.

I'm not sure how your quickview is structured, but if you open it with a .click function and can use jquery use the [.on() function][1].

For example: I use a quickview that opens on a button click. My button is attached to my product-grid-item.liquid with this bit of code:

```html
<div class="quick-view-button">
<a class="quick-view" data-handle="{{ product.handle }}" href="javascript:void(0);">Quick View</a>
</div>
```

My quickview function originally looked like this:

```html
function quickView() {
 $(".quick-view").click(function () {
 //all of the quickview code
```

What happens is exactly like you described. The event listeners only loaded on the first product load but nothing after an AJAX load.

Using jquery's .on() binds the event listener to the element meaning when it's loaded in later it'll still have the event. Here's an example of what my code looks like after using .on()

```html
function quickView() {
 $('body').on('click','.quick-view',function(){
```

I really hope this helps you or someone else with this problem.
[1]: http://api.jquery.com/on/